# How to create borderless popup windows?

Tags: html, popup, border, borderless

So a normal popup but without the original borders and styles what comes from the Operating system.

Is there a way to style these popups?

EDIT:
Simply HTML elements are not good like `<div>` because they cannot be on front of the windows in the OS.

Comment: Modern browsers don't let you hijack the screen this way, because the only uses for it are annoying at best and huge security risks at at worst. Why can you possibly want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘Chromeless’ pop-up windows used to be allowed in IE via `showModalDialog`, `showModelessDialog` and `createPopup`, but were a disaster for usability and security reasons. They allowed any web page to fake UI on any part of the screen (effectively ‘click-jacking’ the entire desktop, circumventing all security-related UI), and were typically used for the most obnoxious advertising.

IE introduced restrictions on them (dialog `unadorned` is not available to web pages, and `createPopup` popups can no longer obscure other windows) which are not going to go away, and other browsers never implemented them at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can just display an HTML element in front of the web-page. Take a look at w3viewer.com. Click on the "About" link in the bottom left corner.

Comment: The problem with HTML elements are that they cannot be in front of other windows including the browser.

Comment: @CIRK Consider reformulating your question with "popup window" instead of just "popup".

Comment: Updated. :) But hey w3viewer is awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is basically no. You generally cannot style windowed content in a browser...it is possible to style scrollbars and a few other elements in some browsers but nothing can be consistently done to change the browsers 'chrome'.